# Converting HTML to DITA with h2d.xsl

Tags: xslt, tidy, dita

Used tidy to convert some HTML to XML and now want to use it with DITA-OT. I ran h2d.xsl via Oxygen on it but the output does not validate in DITA. E.g. images wrapped in b tags. I get that h2d.xsl does useful things like adding topic IDs, but I don't get why it creates XML that doesn't validate. Are there parameters or does anyone have a better XSL?

Answer (score 4):

Create in Oxygen a new DITA topic in the Author visual editing mode.
Open the HTML content in the web browser, select all, copy and then paste in the topic you created earlier.
Oxygen will attempt to convert the HTML content to DITA.

This is also done with special XSLT code developed by Oxygen. The main XSLT for this is located in:

```
OXYGEN_INSTALL_DIR\frameworks\dita\resources\xhtml2ditaDriver.xsl
```

and you can also try to create a transformation for it and apply it to the XHTML content.

You can also convert HTML to XHTML by using Oxygen's **File->Import->HTML File** menu entry.

Comment: All of the above are good suggestions, except that I have about 250 files to convert (sorry, should've stated that in the original question). Looking at the validation errors (many, but mostly the same error) I think it'll be easier to write a supplementary transform to fix rather than tweak the existing XSLs.